# load_resource get a nil resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan

In my controller I have:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def create

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I get `undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass`

```
Failures:

1) UsersController if the user passes all the authorizations POST #create should create a new User with some parameters
 Failure/Error: post :create, :user => { :email => 'puppa@puppa.pup' }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:47:in `block in create'
 # ./app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:66:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.10714 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

I was expecting `load_resources` to populate `@user = User.new(params[:user])`

I was looking at CanCan internals following the entire flow and I discovered that in `controller_resource.rb` when we reach `#build_resource` we have:

```
def build_resource
  resource = resource_base.new(resource_params || {})
  assign_attributes(resource)
end
```

But `resource` here is `nil`... it's normal? what I'm missing? It's related with my problem with create action?

EDIT

here is my `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    # Define abilities for the passed in user here. For example:

    # check if the user is registered or a guest user (not logged in)
    if user.present?

      if user.any_role? :super_admin
        can :manage, :all
      end

      if user.any_role? :admin
        can :manage, [User, Institution, Project, Order]
      end

      if user.any_role? :user
        can :show, Project
        can [:add, :change], :cart
        can [:create, :show], Order, :user_id => user.id
        can :download, UrlConnector
      end

    end
  end
end
```

EDIT 2

While calling POST create I have:

in RSpec environment:

```
resource_base: User
resource_class: User
@params: {"user"=>{"email"=>"puppa@puppa.pup"}, "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"create"}
```

in browser as `superadmin` or `admin`, it's the same:

```
resource_base: User
resource_class: User
@params: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"95qQ4H/+CLU96jCIO6U/YtgIQ5zWxE7pg0BedVMPSGk=", "user"=>{"email"=>"estanost@alumnes.ub.edu", "password"=>"264763", "password_confirmation"=>"264763", "ragionesociale"=>"fff", "partitaiva"=>"12345678901", "address"=>"via plutarco, 36", "city"=>"Manduria", "cap"=>"74024", "phone"=>"099979456", "role_ids"=>["3"]}, "commit"=>"Create User", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"users"}
```

Comment: Can you also paste your `ability.rb` ?

Comment: What's the name of the controller?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy UsersController, I've added it. thanks

Comment: Can you show us what is in `params` when `create` gets called?

Comment: Thanks; the controller is named appropriately; `load_resources` should be able to set @user to User.new(...) correctly. Since you are able to debug through the cancan internals, try figuring out what the values are for `resource_base` and `resource_class` ; might show why @user is not being set.

Comment: @gylaz added `@params` value in EDIT2, thanks!

Comment: @PrakashMurthy added `resource_base` and `resource_class` in EDIT2, thank you

Comment: And you are logged in as admin or superadmin?

Comment: @gylaz currently I'm testing it through RSpec, mocking the authorization using something like that `controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(action, subject).and_return('passed!')` but I'll try the same thing in real browser both as Admin and SuperAdmin and I'll report here.

Comment: @gylaz done and added to EDIT2, I don't see any difference there. thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a stacktrace with the error?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I've added the stacktrace, just after the controller. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try placing cancan as the last gem in the Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of the `if user.present?` block, add `user ||= User.new` where that `if` block starts. This way, you will always have a user object. Of course, it won't pass any of your cancans, so the rest should fall through gracefully.